# ASP.NET - Foreach last element appears on whole list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, foreach, dropdownbox

This just drives me nuts. After populating list with `cont` records it changes
so every value is the same. The value is the one from the last record.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var cont = db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
    var list = new List<SelectListItem> ();
    SelectListItem ctr = new SelectListItem();

    foreach (var item in cont)
    {
        ctr.Text = item.Email;
        ctr.Value = item.Email;
        list.Add(ctr);

        //last iteration everything is fine, every element of list holds
        //another value
    }       

   // debugger shows that all list elements have the same text and value
   TempData["list"] = list;

   return View();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create a new `SelectListItem` for every item you want to add. As it is, you are using the *same* `SelectListItem` for every addition, and are just changing the properties every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are adding and editing the same object `ctr` each iteration. It is a **reference type** so every time you do `ctr.*something*` without initializing a new object for `ctr` to reference too, you will be editing the same one.

```
foreach (var item in cont)
{
    SelectListItem ctr = new SelectListItem();
    ctr.Text = item.Email;
    ctr.Value = item.Email;
    list.Add(ctr);
}
```

Move `SelectListItem ctr = new SelectListItem();` into the list

Comment: thank you very much! it worked

Comment: @AleksanderDudek - you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the **SelectListItem ctr = new SelectListItem()** inside the foreach loop, otherwise you will be adding the same object in the list multiple times, and when you change the value of the object you will change the value of the entire list.